# project type is not supported - VS 2005 web service

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2005

I tried to open the VS 2005 web service project on a new laptop - window 7 32 bit professional. It shows the below message -

[image: project open fail]

I already installed VS 2005 professional on this laptop.

What kind of components should I install more? Thank you.

Comment: Where did that come from? I notice that 2009 is four years after 2005 so, maybe it's newer that VS2005?